# How do I publish the message to the rostopic /turtlesim/pose so that the turtle goes to the origin?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
kv@kv:~$ rostopic pub -1 /turtle1/pose turtlesim/Pose -- ['0.0','0.0','0.0','2.0','0.0']
ERROR: Not enough arguments:
 * Given: [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0]]
 * Expected: ['x', 'y', 'theta', 'linear_velocity', 'angular_velocity']

Args are: [x y theta linear_velocity angular_velocity]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227588/how-do-i-publish-the-message-to-the-rostopic--/turtlesim/pose-so-that-the-turtle-goes-to-the-origin?/) by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two part answer:

1. You are publishing incorrectly. The command should be something like:

   rostopic pub --once /turtle1/pose turtlesim/Pose "{x: 0.0, y: 0.0, theta: 0.0, linear_velocity: 0.0, angular_velocity: 0.0}"
2. You cannot teleport the turtle by publishing to the `pose` topic. You need to use a service call:

   rosservice call /turtle1/teleport_absolute ... # Use tab-tab and it will auto-fill the '...'

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on 2016-02-25**:
Thanks..that worked!
How can I generate trajectory for the turtle to move between two given co-ordinates?

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-25**:
You would need to write a planner/controller to do that. Or use one of the existing ones. I highly recommend you (at least) skim through most of the ROS tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials and http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials